# Method to solve a non-linear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

Hello everyone out here,

I am trying to tackle a problem which requires to solve the following differential equation on the domain $D=(0, +\infty)$:
$$
g''(x)+ \frac{g^{2}(x)}{x^5}=-\frac{1}{x^3},
$$
where the function $g(x)$ should be smooth enough to ensure that the second derivative is well-defined.
I am quite sure that there is no nontrivial solution to this equation, but I cannot prove it: I'm thus looking for techniques to solve this equation.

Thanks for the help on this matter.

Answer (score 4):

Maple says the solution is
$$
g(x) = -6\;x\;\wp\left(-\frac{1}{x} + C_1, -\frac13, C_2\right)
$$
where $\wp(z, g_2, g_3)$ is the [Weierstrass elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) .

Comment: That $1/3$ should be $-1/3$, I think.

Comment: $-1/3$ is correct, thanks.

Comment: It remains to find out when this function is smooth on $(0,+\infty)$, that is has no real poles. Unfortunately the question does not specify whether a real  solution is required or it can be complex.

Comment: Assuming the constants are real, the Weierstrass elliptic function has equally-spaced poles on the real axis, so this function will never be smooth on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Hi Alexendre,  regarding your point I must say that I am looking for a real solution. Besides, the smooth of the solution is not a mandatory condition. Than for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

The note by J. Drach, *Sur l'intégration, par quadratures, de l'équation* $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=F(x,y)$, Comptes Rendus Acad. Sci. Paris, **168** (1919) 497-501 describes the conditions under which equations of this type can be integrated.